# Definition of convergence of real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We say a sequence converges to a real number l if given any epsilon greater than 0 there exists a natural number N such that after the first N-1 terms all the remaining terms of the sequence lie in epsilon symmetric neighborhood of l i.e|xn-l|<epsilon after first N-1 terms.Here instead of less than can I take less than or equal to?Is there any problem if I do so.

Comment: Yes you can take , there is nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an equivalent definition.

Consider the  conditions:

(1) For all $\epsilon > 0$, we eventually have $|x_n - l| < \varepsilon$.

(2) For all $\epsilon > 0$, we eventually have $|x_n - l| \leq \varepsilon$.

It is obvious that condition (1) implies condition (2), for the same $\varepsilon$.

Conversely, assume (2) is true and let us prove (1) for some given value   $\varepsilon > 0$. This follows immediately from the fact that (2) is true with $\varepsilon$ replaced by $\varepsilon/2$.